# Get value from java lang object on hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have query:

```
public List<InvoiceItems> findAllBalance(String external_key) throws HibernateException {
          return (List<InvoiceItems>) session.createQuery("select SUM(i.amount) as amount, t.record_id from Accounts a, InvoiceItems i, Tenant t WHERE a.record_id = i.account_record_id AND t.record_id=a.tenant_record_id  AND a.external_key='"+external_key+"' group by i.tenant_record_id, t.record_id").list();
    }
```

InvoiceItems.java:

```
package id.co.keriss.consolidate.ee;

import java.util.Date;

import org.jpos.ee.Accounts;

    public class InvoiceItems {

        private long record_id;
        private String id;
        private String type;
        private String invoice_id;
        private Accounts account_record_id;
        private Tenant tenant_record_id;
        private String description;
        private long amount;
        private Date created_date;
        private String usage_name;
        private String plan_name;
        private String account_id;



        public String getAccount_id() {
            return account_id;
        }
        public void setAccount_id(String account_id) {
            this.account_id = account_id;
        }
        public long getRecord_id() {
            return record_id;
        }
        public void setRecord_id(long record_id) {
            this.record_id = record_id;
        }
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public String getInvoice_id() {
            return invoice_id;
        }
        public void setInvoice_id(String invoice_id) {
            this.invoice_id = invoice_id;
        }
        public Accounts getAccount_record_id() {
            return account_record_id;
        }
        public void setAccount_record_id(Accounts account_record_id) {
            this.account_record_id = account_record_id;
        }
        public Tenant getTenant_record_id() {
            return tenant_record_id;
        }
        public void setTenant_record_id(Tenant tenant_record_id) {
            this.tenant_record_id = tenant_record_id;
        }
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
        public long getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }
        public void setAmount(long amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }
        public Date getCreated_date() {
            return created_date;
        }
        public void setCreated_date(Date created_date) {
            this.created_date = created_date;
        }
        public String getUsage_name() {
            return usage_name;
        }
        public void setUsage_name(String usage_name) {
            this.usage_name = usage_name;
        }
        public String getPlan_name() {
            return plan_name;
        }
        public void setPlan_name(String plan_name) {
            this.plan_name = plan_name;
        }


    }
```

then set to an variable:

```
List<InvoiceItems> invoiceItems = invoiceItemsDao.findAllBalance(jsonRecv.getString("externalkey"));
```

I want to get the value from that query, what I try:

```
LogSystem.info(request, "List : " + invoiceItems.get(0).getId();
```

I got an error "can't cast to InvoiceItems"

then I try changing from `List<InvoiceItems>` to just `List`

get with this :

```
LogSystem.info(request, "List : " + invoiceItems.get(0);
```

but the output like this not the value:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@41ea9df8
```

any advice? final result what i want is calculate amount of tenant

Comment: Please share the code for `InvoiceItems`

Comment: have added to post for InvoiceItems.java @Susanta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session.createQuery take HQL (Hibernate query language) however I see you use native SQL. Try using createSQLQuery method.

```
public List<InvoiceItems> findAllBalance(String external_key) throws HibernateException {
     Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select SUM(i.amount) as amount, t.record_id from Accounts a, InvoiceItems i, Tenant t WHERE a.record_id = i.account_record_id AND t.record_id=a.tenant_record_id  AND a.external_key='"+external_key+"' group by i.tenant_record_id, t.record_id");
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(InvoiceItems.class));
     List<InvoiceItems> list = query.list();
        return list;
}
```

Comment: i got this:
Hibernate: /* dynamic native SQL query */ select SUM(i.amount) as amount, t.record_id from Accounts a, InvoiceItems i, Tenant t WHERE a.record_id = i.account_record_id AND t.record_id=a.tenant_record_id  AND a.external_key='MT2' group by i.
tenant_record_id, t.record_id
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01

ERROR: relation "invoiceitems" does not exist

what i miss ?

Comment: This is a SQL query error. does this table/view Invoiceitems exist in database?

Comment: did you try running the query directly in DB client?

Comment: Yes, on java too i have try query just for InvoiceItems without join and that is success

Comment: try this query itself in db?