# How to assign a native query result to a Pojo Class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.2

I am using JPA with hibernate in my project.

I came to a query where I need to join 6 tables.
This will give 20 columns as a result.

My Entity classes are:

- InvoiceAccount
- AssetAgreement
- Asset
- LineItem
- ProductAgreement
- Product

My pojo class is AggregateDetail which contain all the 20 variables that I will get from the native query.

Is there any way to implement this.

Comment: You may use CreateSQLQuery along with Result transformer to achieve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545239/get-value-from-java-lang-object-on-hibernate/55545543#55545543

Comment: In that example InvoiceItems seems to be an Entity class. But I need to assingn the result to a non entity class

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
List<? extends Object> results=entityManager.createQuery("YOUR QUERY").getResultList();
```

Finally you can cast the result, of course after testing each object.

Comment: what does "?" means here

Comment: This means any class extends from Object, as you know all the classes in JAVA extends Object class, so this mean any class you want.

Comment: Also you must know there a is difference between List<? extends Object> and List<Object> the second one mean that this list accept just classes just of type Object.